# Color picker ant design

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

как поменять цвет текста внутри pop up color picker ant design?

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, Ваш код

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.ant-select-selection-item{
  color:red;
}

.ant-input{
  color: green;
}

.ant-input-number-input-wrap .ant-input-number-input{
  color: red;
}
```